# Trying to get my CoreData to display in my app

Tags: ios, core-data, storyboard

I am playing around, learning CoreData and when I got a test application with a UITableView as the root, and it displays the data fine. This would tell me that the database it is pulling the data from is set up correct.

Now I am trying to to have a UIViewController as the initial view controller (via Story board) and it keeps giving me this error -

> Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model

Now I have read a lot of forums and Tutorials and they all basically say that I need to make sure that my xcdatamodel file matches this

> URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"]

and it does, again I can display the data if the UITableView is the root view.

Now if I change:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
{
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
  NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model"     withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

into this:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
{
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
  //NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model"   withExtension:@"momd"]; // I have commented out this line because the NSURL is no longer being used.
__managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
return __managedObjectModel;
 }
```

The app runs but the TableView is empty, which makes sense to me, as I am not linking to the CoreData file. - The question is- how can I run the app with the setup I have got and show the data?

Cheers Jeff

---

@response to first answer by Jeff Wolski

Thanks for the answer, I think I am on the right path - I had to alter it slightly to my project to remove the errors. I know have

```
AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

So I have put this is the

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
```

Area - is that correct? Also it now has come up with appDelegate variable is not used warning. May be a simple issue, but where do I use that variable now? Cheers Jeff

---

I have posted what I think is what you are after @Jody Hagins - Hope it helps:-)

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ViewToNav.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];


NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
{

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Cheers Jeff

Comment: What does your persistentStoreCoordinator() look like?

Comment: Hi Jody, I have added more code of what i think you are asking:-)

Comment: Your code here to access the App delegate is wrong.. you are not even using pointers... It's right in Jeff's post.  Go look there again.  Also, I think you should go look at the apple-generated code for a good example because I think you are confused.  Easy way: In Xcode, select New Project, then select Master-Detail and check CoreData project.  It will create a project with a good example of how to do this..

Comment: I have checked and just rechecked the Core Data project - the template starts with a UITableView Controller which is cool, but I need it to start from a plain UIViewController and have access the TableViewController via a button going to a Segue then. That is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up all of your core data in your app delegate.  The managed object model needs to be a property in your app delegate that your views can access.  In your view controller, you can get a hook to your app delegate with

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

This will allow you to perform a fetch from whatever view controller you like.

EDIT:

The reason we need to have the `appDelegate` in the view controller is so that we can access the `NSManagedObjectContext` that's in the app delegate.  So you don't need to put the `NSManagedObjectModel` in your view controller.  The `NSManagedObjectContext` (MOC) gives you access to the entire core data stack that already exists in your app delegate.

In your app delegate, your MOC should be set up as a property.  Now you can do this in your view controller.

```
myMOC = appDelegate.MOC;
```

Now `myMOC` gives you access to your core data.  You will create a `NSFetchedResultsController` as a property in your view controller.  In your getter method, one of the steps will be to create a `NSEntityDescription`.  This is where you use your `self.myMOC`, thus tying your `NSFetchedResultsController` to your core data model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I am on the right path - I had to alter it slightly to my project to remove the errors. I know have 
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
So I have put this is the "- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{" Area - is that correct?

Also it now has come up with appDelegate variable is not used warning. May be a simple issue, but where do I use that variable now?

Cheers

Comment: I have copied my response to the question as to avoid confusion of the code. Cheers

Comment: Ok, I am starting to understand it now, but still going to hunt for the write place to put this - thanks for the tips. I may post back if I have any other questions:-)